# Any way to move the mediaController in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone kindly let me know is there any way to move the media controller(inbuilt android mediaController) to anywhere desired.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class ConstantAnchorMediaController extends MediaController {
   public ConstantAnchorMediaController(Context context, View anchor)     {
      super(context);   
      super.setAnchorView(anchor);  
   }    
  @Override  
   public void setAnchorView(View view)     {  
       // Do nothing   
  } 
}
```

you can use this MediaController to set the Anchor to whichever view you desire